# aam-opencv build producing errors

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

i am trying to build aam-opencv following the brief tutorial from the sources [**website here**](https://code.google.com/p/aam-opencv/) . I keep recieveing the error:

```
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

C:\aam-opencv\build>cmake ..
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 17.0.61030.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 17.0.61030.0
CMake Error at cmake/modules/FindOpenCV.cmake:239 (MESSAGE):
  OpenCV required but some headers or libs not found.  Please specify it's
  location with OpenCV_ROOT_DIR env.  variable.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:48 (FIND_PACKAGE)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I have tried using the variable `OpenCV_ROOT_DIR="c:\opencv-2.4.9\opencv\build`, but that also produced the same error.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope someone else will find my answer helpful. After about a week of searching I came across a brief tutorial online. Doing this made it possible. (Although getting the application to run, requires some debugging to let it work with windows)

If you want to without cygwin but with Visual C++, you need following:

**1) CMake 2.6 or later**

**2) OpenCV Ver 1.0** <- The OpenCV Version is Crucial in this tutorial

**3) Qt 2.6.1 or later**

**1) CMake**
download cmake from http://www.cmake.org/files/v2.8/cmake-2.8.2-win32-x86.exe
install with default option

**2) OpenCV ver. 1.0**
download from http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-win/1.0/OpenCV_1.0.exe/download

install with default option.

**3) Qt  4.6.3**
download Qt for Open Source C++ development on Windows (VS2008) from http://qt.nokia.com/downloads/windows-cpp-vs2008

**Build:**
set System Environment variable OpenCV_ROOT_DIR to C:\Program Files\OpenCV

Download aam-opencv.rar from attached to this article.
Extract  aam-opencv.rar to somewhere you want (e.g. D:\Project \aam)

**Open `D:\Project\aam\aam-opencv\src\opencvWebcam.cpp`
modify line 51**
If you want to use movie file, specify your movie file path. 
Note that you have to specify path using \ as path separator.
If you want to use webcam, comment line 51 and uncomment line 52.

**run CMake gui**
Select for "D:\Project\aam\aam-opencv" as "Where is the source folder" option
Select for "D:\Project\aam\aam-opencv\build" as "Where to build the binaries" option

**Click "Configure" button**
Then, You will see generator option.
Select "Visual Studio 9 2008"
if  needed,select C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin\cl.exe  as c compiler and cxx compiler.

**Click "Generate" button.**

Then, You can see D:\Project\aam\aam-opencv\build\AAM.sln
Open D:\Project\aam\aam-opencv\build\AAM.sln with your Visual C++
Build Solution.

**Congratulations!**

Now you can run q-aamtrainer.exe from VC ++ menu, select Debug -> Start Debugging by selecting `D:\Project\aam\aam-opencv\build\Debug\qt-aamtrainer.exe`

**NOTE:** After I complete debugging and get this application working i will link or update to my answer, keep posted!

**UPDATE** I was not able to get it to run on windows, if anyone has a solution, comment or link to the answer.